# How to check if widget is visible using FlutterDriver

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am not sure how I would check whether a widget is currently shown or not using [`FlutterDriver`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/FlutterDriver-class.html).

Using [`WidgetTester`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester-class.html) this is really easy to perform using e.g. [`findsOneWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/findsOneWidget-constant.html).
However, during integration tests using `FlutterDriver`, there is no access to a `WidgetTester` object.

The [`FlutterDriver.waitFor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/FlutterDriver/waitFor.html) method does not indicate whether the widget was found in the given duration.

How do I check whether a widget is on screen using `FlutterDriver`?

Comment: What's the use-case? That may not be what you want. Integration tests shouldn't care about how widget-tree looks like.

Comment: But would widget testing be possible? Widget-testing can be used for small integration tests too.

Comment: @RémiRousselet No, it is not. I can currently avoid the problem by taking manual action while the integration test is running because it only happens at some point, however, this is bad for automation as I cannot always ensure that the integration test runs all the way.

Comment: You can get item's measurements

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Flutter Driver doesn't have explicit method to check if a widget is present / exists, but we can create a custom method which will serve the purpose using `waitFor` method. For example, I have a simple `text` widget on screen and I will write a flutter driver test to check if that widget is present or not using a custom method `isPresent`.

Main code:

```
body: Center(
      child:
      Text('This is Test', key: Key('textKey'))
```

Flutter driver test to check if this widget is present or not is as below:

```
test('check if text widget is present', () async {
      final isExists = await isPresent(find.byValueKey('textKey'), driver);
      if (isExists) {
        print('widget is present');
      } else {
        print('widget is not present');
      }
    });
```

`isPresent` is custom method whose definition is as below:

```
isPresent(SerializableFinder byValueKey, FlutterDriver driver, {Duration timeout = const Duration(seconds: 1)}) async {
  try {
    await driver.waitFor(byValueKey,timeout: timeout);
    return true;
  } catch(exception) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Running the test detects the widget is present:

[image]

If I comment out the `text` widget code and then run the test, it detects that widget is not present:

[image]

Comment: Can we make the test fail intentionally if the widget is not present?

Comment: @Donki: just use an expect: `expect(await isPresent(find.byValueKey('textKey'), driver), isTrue);`

Comment: Hi... I try to use this but i got error like  "Unexpected <collected> sentinel."